# The breaker trips when switch is put back on

Tags: wiring

The ceiling box has 2 red wires twisted together,2 grey wires twisted together and a bare copper wire coming out.I attached the black from the new fixture to the red,the white to the grey and the green to the bare.When the breaker was put back on the light/fan came on with the light switch in off position (constant feed??).I can operate the light/fan with the remote but if the switch is put ON the breaker trips.Any response will be helpful.Thx

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add detail.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the only wires in the box are red and gray proves without a doubt that your installation is in conduit.

I gather there was never a light there before?

It is standard operating procedure in conduit to not install wires until they are needed.  They are rather easy to fish.

So you need to go to the switch and look at the wiring there.  How is the switch connected? Has it always tripped the breaker?   Then figure out which pipe coming into the switch connects to which pipe at the lamp.  Add that to your question and we can guide further.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the wires were connected that way before you did it right…

I don’t think it was it is a switch loop and now when you turn the switch on you create a direct short.

This is also why it runs with the fan in the off position

You will end up with a grey and red together to correctly wire this. You need the hot red connected to the gray to the switch.
Then the red coming back from the switch is your hot and the gray is the neutral

Comment: I thought the same at first, but wondering why it did not trip the breaker before.  I think I am missing something.

Comment: Crip659, with the switch off there is no connection, this is a common DIY mistake an emergency call out for this I used to charge 250 and would be done in 15 minutes and that includes hanging the fixture.